# How to change element's view in JList after adding to ListModel?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlist

How can i change element's view in `JList` after adding array(-s) to `ListModel`.
Needed:

```
2.0 11.0 1.0
```

Having:

```
[D@198dfaf
```

I really don't want to use "array to string" conversion before adding and after getting from `JList`..
Is there any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) for that purpose. It allows you to return a Component that represents the value you have put in the model of the JList.

The default CellRenderer is the [DefaultListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html) which is basically an extension of a JLabel and with all the proper look & feel settings already set. So you could extend DefaultListCellRenderer and set the array-text on the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to changing renderer, or overriding `toString()` you can consider adding a view adapter for the objects you add to the list. Something similar to this simplified example:

```
class ArrayListViewAdapter {
    Object[] list;

    public ArrayListViewAdapter(Object[] list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return StringUtils.join(list, " ");
    }
}
```

Then to add items to the model:

```
model.addElement(new ArrayListViewAdapter(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}));
```